# java input must take from customer and it must be in sequential way

Tags: java

Write a java program to ask the user for his/her name, age, and salary (double). Follow the input/output format.

Following conversation should be displayed as output on screen, where you will enter the values of name,age and salary.

Suppose your inputs are:

John

22

500
Expected Output:

Hello. What is your name? 
 Hi John! How old are you? 
 So you're 22 eh? That's not old at all! 
 How much do you make John?

500.0! I hope that's per hour and not per year! LOL!

i try to solve like this

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class Enquiry
{ 
 public static void main(String args[])
 { 
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in); 
  do{ 
     System.out.println("Hello. What is your name?"); 
     string name1 = scanner.nextString(); 
    }
  while(name1 != null) 
    { 
     System.out.println("Hi" +name1 "! How old are you?"); 
     int age = scanner.nextInt(); 
    } 
  while(age != null) 
     { 
     System.out.println("So you're" +age "eh? That's not old at all!");                     System.out.println("How much do you make John?"); 
     double salary = scanner.nextDouble(); 
     }
  while(salary != null)
    { 
     System.out.println(+salary"! I hope that's per hour and not per year! LOL!"); 
     } 
  } 
}
```

can any one help me how to solve this and what are mistakes done by me
thanks and really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of mistakes, like

1.) There is no need for `do - while loops`.

2.) String is concatenated with `+` operator, missing in `system.out.println()` statements.

3.) `string name1`, `S` should be in uppercase, `String` is a java keyword, referring to a datatype.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello. What is your name?");
        String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hi" + name1 + "! How old are you?");
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So you're" + age + "eh? That's not old at all!");
        System.out.println("How much do you make John?");
        double salary = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(+salary + "! I hope that's per hour and not per year! LOL!");
    }
```

**Output**

```
Hello. What is your name?
John
HiJohn! How old are you?
22
So you're22eh? That's not old at all!
How much do you make John?
500
500.0! I hope that's per hour and not per year! LOL!
```